# How can display value from this multidimensional array?

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array, advanced-custom-fields

How can i receive image url from this given array and display inside a image tag? From this below array you will get every input you need. This value retrieved from database and store in a array variable. I want to display Value from this array using wordpress loop

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(18) {
    ["ID"]=>
    int(32)
    ["id"]=>
    int(32)
    ["title"]=>
    string(15) "President Image"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(11) "3f666ad.jpg"
    ["url"]=>
    string(63) "http://localhost/moderna/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/3f666ad.jpg"
    ["alt"]=>
    string(15) "President Image"
    ["author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["caption"]=>
    string(17) "This is a caption"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "3f666ad"
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2015-08-25 05:18:16"
    ["modified"]=>
    string(19) "2015-08-31 14:05:45"
    ["mime_type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "image"
    ["icon"]=>
    string(61) "http://localhost/moderna/wp-includes/images/media/default.png"
    ["width"]=>
    int(200)
    ["height"]=>
    int(200)
```

Comment: `$array[0]['url']` will give `url` of image, and in loop `foreach($array as $k => $v) { $v['url']; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  echo $result[0]['url'];
```

If it has many indexes use `foreach`

```
   $ImgArr = [];
  foreach($result as $key => $val){
   $ImgArr[] = $val['url'];
  }
   print_r($ImgArr');
```